# Not able to create scene with SpriteKit in Xcode Playgrounds

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I am trying to create a very simple scene using spriteKit in Xcode Playgrounds. I want to create a button which will then respond to my click. I also want to be able to create my own frame size.

I am using the code below and it is giving me all sorts of errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Frame {    
let view:SKView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768))
let scene:SKScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
view.presentScene(scene)

var startButton = UIButton(type: .system)
startButton.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 500, width: 50, height: 10)
startButton.tintColor = .blue
startButton.setTitle("Next", for:.normal)
view.addSubview(startButton)


func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        if self.atPoint(touch.location?) == self.startButton{
        }
    }
}
}
```

I get the following errors
expected declaration: line with `scene.scaleMode`
expected declaration: line with `startButton.frame`
value of type 'Frame' has no member 'atPoint': line with `if self.atPoint...`

Comment: you are missing a } at the end of the file to close the class in the code above,not sure if that is how it is in xCode for you currently. What are the errors its giving you?

Comment: Just added it in the edit. Also about the bracket, I just forgot to copy it :) @Steve

Comment: It turns out that it wasn't working because I forgot the load view method.  
You need this  

func loadView() {  
}